# httpget controller and localization

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In sturtup i use:

```
 var locale = "ru-RU";
            RequestLocalizationOptions localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {               
                SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo(locale) },
                SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo(locale) },
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(locale),
            };
```

In this controller:

```
[HttpPost] 
        public async Task<IActionResult> Test(SearchModel searchModel)
        {
           decimal sum = searchModel.Sum;
```

work true, but when i get decimal in query params localization not work:

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(decimal? sum)
        {
           decimal sum_ = sum;//when i enter 1,2 controller in sum_ 12.0
```

Comment: you should enter 1.2 with dot. It is decimal.

Comment: no in first controller 1,2 its decimal, in russian localization comma is separator, but in second controller its incorent work

Comment: so you try parse with your culture like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131414/culture-invariant-decimal-tryparse

Comment: Note that the question is asking how to use correct culture for model binding (and hopefully a way shown in the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44688311/how-to-set-culture-for-date-binding-in-asp-net-core) is correct), if that is not what you are looking for please [edit] question so readers are not confused.